# Getting the object name through the Ghidra Script

Tags: binary-analysis, ghidra

I have a script written to work with Ghidra. I am doing some analysis in the script and save the results in a file. Right now, I am passing the name when a prompt ask the file name to save upon running the script. Though this is ok for one, I need to run this script in more than 100 objects at once(using the headless analyzer) and I want the file name to automatically taken from the object name. How could I do this?

For example, let's say I have an object file called `mqtt.o`. I need to take this name (`mqtt`) while saving the file which contains the results. I looked through the API, but still could not find a way to get the name of the object of analysis. Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, it sounds like you want to use the name of the file you're analyzing to determine the name of the file your script outputs. If so, [`getProgramFile()`](https://ghidra.re/ghidra_docs/api/ghidra/program/flatapi/FlatProgramAPI.html#getProgramFile()) is probably the easiest way to grab it.